# How to get rid of bug stuck into eyes?

Tags: cleaning, safety, air, eyesight

Recently I was coming back home on motorcycle (without helmet) while a bug went into my eyes. Holding and closing my terrible burning left eye I came back home. Using the general technique of tap water splashing into eyes didn't worked for a long time. It was tiny and not like dust which could come out along with water. Somehow the bug came out at the cost of red eyes. Is there any easy and effective method to get rid of such situation quickly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove dust particles when it accidentally goes into our eyes?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7460/how-to-remove-dust-particles-when-it-accidentally-goes-into-our-eyes)

Comment: @Chenmunka possible but I'm dealing with small bug, not dust and water splashing method didn't worked.

Comment: "Don't have this problem" answers are discouraged, but many places legally require eye protection of some kind (glasses, helmet visors, windshields) for all motorcycle operators, and they're a very, very good idea anywhere -- if that had been a pebble, you might have lost the eye.

Comment: a small bug is an easier case than a dust particle, I've added an answer to that question that'll help.

Comment: @Hobbes The fingertip method is last method and very much painful. In fact this was the thing I did at last resulting in red eyes. Looking for any easy and non-invasive solution

Comment: What's the point? We all know how it's gonna be: you try this and that, to no avail, you end up rubbing your eye violently, but the bug stays there no matter what, until the next morning, when it mysteriously disappears.

Comment: @Headcrab Check my own answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today I went for visiting a hill-station spot and while returning, a tiny fly went into my eyes. Eyes started burning but somehow I drove back home. I started splashing my eyes like water pump machine without any success by end of five minutes. Putting finger and towel tip in eyes only increased the burning and making situation worse. There is a popular technique to blow your eyes with mouth air to take dirt out but no companion was there to help me out.

Suddenly the idea to use bent straw clicked my mind.

[image: Straw]

As shown in picture, I put longer end in my mouth and other end exactly the part of eye containing dead fly. With just two blow, the dead creature came out with a sign of relief on my face. RIP for fly... Amen.

Comment: straw pipe idea is not the bad one....big thanks buddy.

Answer (score 2):

Simple Technique to remove anything trapped under your eyelid.

1. Using your clean fingers, hold the **eyelashes** (of the eyelid with the offending material trapped underneath)
2. Pull it down (or up if its the lower eyelid) and over the other
   eyelash.
3. The eyelash should act as a **brush** and clean out what was
   trapped underneath!

Comment: This is good solution, worth a try

Answer (score 0):

Both the eyes are internally connected. If we twist one eye in one direction, the second eye is automatically twisted in the same direction. If a bug is stucked into one of your eyes, you are advised not to twist the same eye as it can create scratches in that eye. Rather twist the second eye lightly, the stucked eye will be twisted automatically and the bug will come to the boundry line of the eye which you can bring out with the help of some clean piece of cloth.

Answer (score 0):

Take a piece of paper and tear(rip) it into a triangle shape. The triangle should have two long sides and one short side. Fold it gently on a line from the point where the long sides meet, to the middle of the short side. Do not fold it closed like a book, leave it folded at about 90 degrees so it looks more like a pointy spoon

You now have a tool that is great for removing debris from the eye, using the pointy end; it is clean, has soft edges and you will find that it soaks the water of the eye up and causes the debris in the eye to stick to the paper.

If it gets too wet and loses strength, make another one

[image: a piece of paper torn into a triangle and bent for rigidity]

Comment: Good one, may be used when there is no access of straw but still it is invasive method.